# Maven - what groupid is it?

Tags: maven

My example pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>0.1.0</version>

 <build>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.2</version>
     <configuration>
        <mainClass>src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main</mainClass>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

My understanding so far is `groupId` is `unique id of the org which builds this project` and `artifactId` is `name for the version`.

I understand what `groupId artifactId version` from [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html). but i couldn't find what these fields inside a plug-in mean?

Comment: Don't fully understand your question. Is it why do plugins need a `groupid`?

Comment: groupid and artifactId are necessery in plugins that maven can find them in the maven-repository.

Comment: Yes jan. why do plugins need groupid? is it necesary?

Comment: So put together, initial fields meant for the project is being created. Later fields inside plugin means for plugin project details. Am i right?

Comment: <plugins> section is for maven plugins that you'd wish to use, similar to <dependencies> where you declare external projectes (i.e. libraries) that you'd need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`artifactId` is the id of the artifact which can be jar dependency or a maven plugin or some other product released by the organisation denoted by `groupid`, `version` is the version of that artifact.

You are right about the definition of a group id. You may leave out the group id while referencing *official* maven plugins which use the group id `org.apache.maven.plugins`.

So a maven plugin is handled just like any other project dependency.

Comment: Thanks. What is artifact/`product`/plugin ?

Comment: You are saying that `maven plugin is handled just like any other project dependency`. Then can we specify it in dependency?

Comment: No you would just use it in the build section. It is good practice though to add the plugins with the versions you are using in the plugin-dependencies section of the pom and leave out the version information in build section.

Comment: I recommend to take a look at the Sonatype books (Maven By Example, Maven The Complete Reference) See http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html and http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the references :)